# How to merge cells without losting data in libreoffice-calc?

Tags: python-3.x, merge, libreoffice-calc, uno

Launch libreoffice-calc:

```
soffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager"
```

Launch python shell to write data into the `calc`:

```
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
context = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
svcmgr = context.ServiceManager
desktop = svcmgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context)
oDoc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL( "private:factory/scalc","_blank", 0, () )
oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:C3")
```

Write data into `oRange`.

```
oRange.setDataArray((('a1','a2','a3'),('b1','b2','b3'),('c1','c2','c3'),))
```

The calc's appearance now:

[image]

I want to merge all data in `oRange` and format it with vertical and horizontal alignment.
My desired effect in the editing `calc`.
[image]

```
oRange.merge()
oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0)
oCell.HoriJustify = 2
oCell.VertJustify = 2
```

Merged data with vertical and horizontal alignment ,previous data in many cells `b1-c1` and `a2-c2` and `a3-c3` lost.
The real effect.
[image]

How to fix my code to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
import uno
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
context = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext")
svcmgr = context.ServiceManager
desktop = svcmgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context)
oDoc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL( "private:factory/scalc","_blank", 0, () )
oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:C3")
tup = (('a1','a2','a3'),('b1','b2','b3'),('c1','c2','c3'),)
oRange.setDataArray(tup)
target =''
for item in tup:
    tmp = ' '.join(item)
    target = target + tmp + ' '

target = target.strip()
oRange.merge(True)
oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0)
oCell.String = target
oCell.HoriJustify = 2
oCell.VertJustify = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think UNO has no way of knowing that you want to rearrange the data into the merged cell that way. What UNO does is "copy" the data from the "main" cell (the top left one) and "paste" its data into the merged cell. Therefore, what you could do is change the data of the main cell before merging. Check the example below.

```
# get range
oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:C3")

# build string
flat_list = [str(item) for sublist in oRange.getDataArray() for item in sublist]
string = ' '.join(flat_list)

# put string into main cell
main_cell = oRange.getCellByPosition(0, 0) 
main_cell.setString(string)

# merge
oRange.merge()
```